# RabbitMQ consumer is executing and returning undefined error

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, microservices

I am using RabbitMQ and calling the consumer functions in the index file and the functions are executing while the server starts and returns a undefined error I am getting this error while using docker only while running normally without docker I didn't get any error only running on docker causes the error
My index file

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import messageController from './controller/messagecontroller';
import router from './routes/messageRouter';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {Server, Socket} from 'socket.io'

dotenv.config()

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

messageController.userSave()
app.use(router);


const mongoUrl: string | undefined = process.env.MONGO_URL

if (!mongoUrl) {
    console.error('MongoDB connection URL is not defined.');
    process.exit(1);
  }

mongoose.connect(mongoUrl).then(()=>{
    console.log('database connected..');
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log("Database connection error", err);
    
})

const server = app.listen('8004', () => {
    console.log("messaging service listening on PORT 8004");
})
```

my controller function

```
  async userSave() {
    try {
      const userData: any = await userMessageConsumers.userCreatedMessageConsumer()
      const newUser = new UserModel({
        _id: userData._id,
        username: userData.username,
        phone: userData.phone,
        email: userData.email,
        profilePicture: userData.profilePicture,
        createdAt: userData.createdAt,
        updatedAt: userData.updatedAt,
        status: userData.status,
      })
      await newUser.save()
      return
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
```

consumer function

```
async userCreatedMessageConsumer(){
    try{
        console.log("starting rabbit mq channel ");
        const channel = await RabbitMQ.createChannel();
        const exchangeName = 'user-message-exchange';
        const queueName = 'user-message-exchange';
        await channel.assertExchange(exchangeName, 'direct', {durable: false});
        const {queue} = await channel.assertQueue(queueName, {durable: false});
        const routingKey = 'user-message-created';
        await channel.bindQueue(queue ,exchangeName, routingKey);
        return new Promise((resolve ,reject)=>{
            channel.consume(queue, (message: any)=>{
                if(message){
                    try {
                        const createdGig: any = JSON.parse(message.content.toString());
                        channel.ack(message);
                        resolve(createdGig)
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error("error processing gig creation");
                        channel.ack(message);
                        reject(error)
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        await channel.close()
        
    }catch(err){
        console.error("error setting up consumer", err)
    }
},
```

Comment: What is the **exact** error, and where is occurring?

Comment: @DaveNewton it occurs while the starting of the app says that is _id is undefined the usersave function is executing firstly not waiting for the message receive